# PyMC3: Mixture Model with Latent Variables

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, latent-variable, pymc, finite-mixture-model

I have a rather basic knowledge of Bayesian inference and I'm somewhat new to MCMC and PyMC3. Can I model data that looks like this?

```
X1 = stats.poisson.rvs(5,size=100)
X2 = stats.poisson.rvs(10,size=100)
t = stats.beta.rvs(5,2,size=100)

Z1 = X1*t
Z2 = X2*t
```

`Z1` and `Z2` are observed values, `X1` and `X2` are the latent variables I care about inferring, and `t` is unobserved.

Is it possible to trace posteriors for the hyper-parameters of `X1`, `X2` and maybe `t` also?

Comment: Pymc3 has an entire functionality for mixtures https://docs.pymc.io/api/distributions/mixture.html.  You should also try the discord site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not call this a mixture model, but you can model it with PyMC.  Getting the MCMC to converge might be a pain, though, because the parameter space is pretty high dimensional.

Let me refactor your data generating procedure to put the data in a DataFrame:

```
import pymc3 as pm, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
N = 100

mu_1_true = 5
mu_2_true = 10
alpha_true = 5
beta_true = 2

X1 = stats.poisson.rvs(mu_1_true, size=N)
X2 = stats.poisson.rvs(mu_2_true, size=N)
t = stats.beta.rvs(alpha_true, beta_true, size=N)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Z1'] = X1*t
df['Z2'] = X2*t
```

Then one way to try to recover the mu_1 and mu_2 values from the data in PyMC is this:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    mu1 = pm.Uniform('mu1', lower=0, upper=20)
    mu2 = pm.Uniform('mu2', lower=0, upper=20)
    alpha = alpha_true
    beta = beta_true
    
    t = pm.Beta('t', alpha=alpha, beta=beta, shape=N)
    
    Z1 = pm.Poisson('Z1', mu=mu1*t, observed=df.Z1)
    Z2 = pm.Poisson('Z2', mu=mu2*t, observed=df.Z2)
    trace = pm.sample(500, cores=2)
```

The estimates come in a little low when I try it, so maybe there is still room for improvement:[image]

Here is a notebook with all the details in context: https://gist.github.com/aflaxman/b98d3212f59ce24f667225de1fbfafbd

Answer (score 0):

You should first refer to the examples [here](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/api_quickstart) to learn the usage of PyMC3. Modelling in PyMC requires its own libraries to be used for RV definitions e.g. `pm.Poisson()`, instead of other well-known libs like `stats`. After careful construction, you should be able to trace your posteriors (`X1`, `X2` and `t`).

Comment: Thank you, but it's the 'careful construction' with which I'm struggling. After defining `Z1` and `Z2` as `pm.Deterministic`, I run into the problem of not being able to 'observe' a Deterministic. I've read up on other people posting with that problem and it seems that perhaps that is the wrong approach to be taking here. I apologise if my question is too vague.